# How to column stack a list and Numpy array and savetxt?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list `A` and a numpy array `B` that are to be stacked column-wise as shown below:

**Input**

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C']

B = [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
     [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
     [11 12 13 14 15 16]]
```

**Desired output**

```
[['A' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6']
 ['B' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11']
 ['C' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15' '16']]
```

I tried using the following code but results in an error:

```
import numpy as np

A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])

np.savetxt('test.txt', np.column_stack((A, B)))
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could specify `fmt` as `'%s'`:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', np.column_stack((A, B)), fmt='%s')
```

The problem is that `fmt='%.18e'` by default and strings in the array such as `'A'` do not represent numerical values.

A list of specifiers is given in the [`savetxt` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) (quoted below) and covered in greater detail in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

> `c` : character
>
> `d` or `i` : signed decimal integer
>
> `e` or `E` : scientific notation with `e` or `E`.
>
> `f` : decimal floating point
>
> `g`,`G` : use the shorter of `e`,`E` or `f`
>
> `o` : signed octal
>
> `s` : string of characters
>
> `u` : unsigned decimal integer
>
> `x`,`X` : unsigned hexadecimal integer

Comment: How to obtain mixed formats? A as string and B as a numerical value.

Comment: @nxcr: I'm not sure I understand your question - when writing to disk with `savetxt` you only write string representations of the values in the array.